# get query string in component

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, query-string

I'm stuck 8 hours cant get query string, I guess my function cant call my params, and how can I get my params

```
url : blabla.com/products?partner_id=732&sku=ABC001
```

I'm using async and wait, I tired always didn't get the object,

this my action

```
export const getProductsSKU = async (params, skuNumber) => {
  try {
    let user = await Storage.get('users')
    params.partnerId = user.partner_id
    if (skuNumber) params.sku = skuNumber

    let options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: Endpoint.PRODUCTS,
      params: toSnakeCase(params)
    }

    let getData = await ApiClient(options)

    getData.data = toCamelCase(getData.data)
    return getData
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

and this call get my action in the component

```
fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { skuNumber } = this.state
    const update = await getProductsSKU(skuNumber)
    this.setState({
      products: update.data
    })
  }
```

and this I call my fetch

```
  {this.state.skuNumber.length === 6 && (
      <SKUViewNew
       skuNumber={this.state.skuNumber}
       products={products}
       productId={products.id}
       productName={products.name}
       imageId={products.imageUrl}
       listuom={products.uoms}
       fetchProducts={() => this.fetchProducts()}
       />
 )}
```

and i expectation : 
get products?partner_id=732&sku=ABC001

current condition:
products?0=ABC001

Comment: Where are you calling `fetchProducts`? Is it inside the class? Have you tried to bind the method to the objet `this.fetchProducts.bind(this)`?

Comment: omg I forget to post those fetch products, currently, I call inside the class

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your question to have the overall class you're having a problem with?

Comment: okay sir, my fault

Comment: @KevinPastor, already updated,

Answer (score 0):

Changing the call from a function wrapper to something like this should work. Essentially, with `.bind(this)` you are telling the method to be called in the current context of the object and not in the context of `SKUViewNew`.

```
<SKUViewNew
    skuNumber={this.state.skuNumber}
    products={products}
    productId={products.id}
    productName={products.name}
    imageId={products.imageUrl}
    listuom={products.uoms}
    fetchProducts={this.fetchProducts.bind(this)}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrow function` expressions have a shorter syntax than function expressions and do not bind their own `this`, aggregates, `super`, or `new.target`. The a`rrow function` is always anonymous. This function expression is best suited for non-method functions. So you can't use it as a `constructor`.

You can use this

```js
fetchProducts={this.fetchProducts}
```